# Path of Exile performance

Tags: path-of-exile

How can I further increase FPS on Path of Exile game?
I have a pc with dual core e6300 intel cpu with 4 gb ddr 2 ram, 1gb ddr3 ATI radeon 4670 and enough bandwidth and memory.I play on lowest settings with deactivated post processing and antialiasing and everything ( everything is on low). When I play, whenever i hit first pack of mobs and start using skill everything starts to lag, the sound disappears, framerate goes crazy and everything gets unplayable.Any advice ( except to get new pc :) )

Comment: You also might post this question on superuser due to its hardware related content: https://superuser.com/

Comment: If you're going to list your hardware, then ask for an answer not involving upgrading hardware I'm not really sure what you want us to do. That being said your GPU is way below minimum specs. If you are able to upgrade at all I would suggest starting there.

Comment: Path of Exile is known for putting the CPU through a lot of work. I'd recommend upgrading that alongside your GPU. Of course, "Just spend the money!" is always an iffy advice, but you won't boost the performance of your CPU by cleaning up your PC, however, ensuring that PoE is the only thing running except for system processes would certainly help, if you are not doing so already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is trying to clean up your pc (e.g. deleting old/temporary files, disk defragmentation...) but I think that doesn't affect the games performance that much. Also check if you have installed the best driver for your hardware.

Nevertheless, if you already lowered all settings and still have lags you really should consider to upgrade your system :). If the hardware below the software is too weak to handle it, there's no chance of getting the game to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having really poor graphics, you can try using the "dynamic resolution" setting, assuming you haven't already. It will try to hit the specified FPS (say, 30), by automatically reducing the resolution.

There are instances where you might have the impression of playing a 8-bit game, but it could be your best chance until you manage to upgrade your system.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new computer.

The hardware you're describing is roughly 10 years old, and was a budget build even then. It's completely unsuitable for running *any* modern games.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated already, upgrading your hardware is going to be your best bet. On the software side, you can try running resource monitor and stopping/disabling any programs or services that are cutting into your CPU or network usage.

Dynamic Resolution is very helpful for graphically flashy builds, but since it still kicks in sometimes on my PC even with the latest and greatest in graphics cards, it may turn your game into Tetris (Gameboy Tetris even). You could try setting your targeted FPS for something really low but not quite a slideshow such as 15 FPS.

If and only if you are running POE with DirectX 9 (not 11), you can edit the game's `production_Config.ini` in `C:\Users\YourNameHere\Documents\My Games\Path of Exile\` to set the texture quality lower than the in game menu allows. The line you're looking for will be `texture_quality` and the higher the value, the worse textures but better performance you will see. It gives diminishing returns though, so anything higher than 4 or 5 won't help any further.

If you don't have an SSD getting one is a huge upgrade to the game since it prevents lag caused by loading assets while playing, and it also just generally speeds up load times by an absurd amount.